# Joomla 3.1: extremely slow in bulk deletion

Tags: joomla

I have a simple script to delete articles from a category, it takes forever to delete about 10k articles, here's my code:

```
//include libraries

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array('id'));
$query->from('#__content');
$query->where('catid = 14');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

$table = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable', array());
foreach ($results as $article)
{
    $table->delete($article->id);
}
```

With this code it take about 12 hours to delete about 3k articles. Am I doing things wrong or this is just how Joomla works?

I could simply do MySQL script to delete rows in #_*content, however that way many related tables would not be processed, for example, #*_assets, #__ucm*, #__contenttagmap, etc.

Answer (score 0):

12 hours is an extremely long time to delete 3k articles. I would expect it to take a minute/couple of minutes.

Try using the following to see if it makes any difference.

**NOTE: Please make sure you have a backup of the database before trying this code!**

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$conditions = array(
    'catid=14');

$query->delete('#__content');
$query->where($conditions);

$db->setQuery($query);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: tested your code, runs without error, but didn't delete anything either. Do you think this approach would also get #__assets, #__ucm* and *all* related tables? I don't see any JTable or ContentModelArticle instance involved. I am afraid if I simply delete records from #__content, there maybe bad consequence as many relations, associations are not properly processed, wrong?

Comment: you can make additions to it to delete data from other tables such as `#__assets`. Have a look at **Deleting a Record** on this: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Comment: AFAIK, to update assets table you need to recompute the lft and rgt values which is trivia without instantiating the model.

Comment: It is NOT trvia.

Most likely the slowness is caused by a corrupted asset table which is something you want to avoid like crazy. Please do not attempt to directly compute the asset nesting values unless you understand what you are doing in the API.

Using the $table->delete() is the right way but delete does not require you to loop through everything, it will take an array directly as input, just like in the admin you can use the checkboxes.

Comment: @Elin: thanks for the array tip! Doubt that the asset table corruped. Experimented on a fresh install: inserted 50k articles with a script, using the JTable instance, basically the insertion time is proportionate to the number of of articles, it starts with few ms when the # of articles is less than, say, a thousand, ends with to 10s when the # of articles get close to 50k. Most of the time are spent on computing lft and rgt.

Comment: Are you doing these all in one category or are they scattered?
3.1.4/3.1.5 has some problems with the JTable class and scripts if you are not explicitly importing the legacy and cms libraries and registering some classeds.

Comment: I think you might want to do it in batches. I bet the table locks are killing you.  Like I said before you could do it by hand in about 30 minutes by patch processing 100 at a time in the UI. Maybe that is the way to go.

Comment: For this particular problem, I've just terminated my script,restored database prior to the time that I mistakenly loaded wrong batch of data. Hopefully I don't need to do this anymore, but if I do, I'll take your advice, thanks Elin.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete 3000 articles by hand by making the filter list length 100, checking all, and then clicking the delete button 30 times.  So clearly the way you are doing it is not what should be happening although basically the theory is right.

Can you please make sure that you have no asset_ids for anything but root.1 that have parent_id == 0? 
Also make sure that all of the articles have properly set up asset ids i.e. make sure that they always are parented to the asset for category 14.

You should be able to use the model to delete an array. But even looping 3000 times should not take 8 hours unless you have come infinite loops that are starting over  and over and triggering the failsafe for runaway loops.

Comment: I certainly overlooked the importing of legacy and cms part, need to take a closer look on that. The assets table structure is a bit confusing: I tried to add an article in catid 14 via backend (not script), however in MySQL I am not seeing 14 as its parent id. Well I think I used a fresh installation, but it could be I messed up somewhere else. Fortunately as of yet, seemingly wrong asset table doesn't affect the display, editing, etc., type of jobs.

Comment: Wrong asset table impacts all of those since it is doing your access checks.  The parent id in the asset table is the asset id of the parent not the id of the parent from the category table, so it would not show as 14. 
The asset table structure is really simple, it's just the asset id, the name (component.model.idfromcomponentable), the asset_id of the parent, the lft rght level.

Comment: By second examination, I think my assets table is fine:  I am seeing, say, 37, which is really id of catid 14 in #__assets table. Also randomly checked other entries, they seem to be consistent. I confirm my observation that the process time is proportional to the number of articles in the category. One of my category has over 80k articles, the process time for saving an article in this category takes about 10+ seconds, 99% in updating assets table.